# Passenger Enterprise edition - "Mass Deployment" clarification

Tags: nginx, phusion-passenger

We're thinking about purchasing a license for Passenger Enterprise, and I'm looking for a better explanation about the "Mass Deployment" feature in Passenger Enterprise Edition.

Say you have Rails 3 applications -

- my_blog
- news_site
- online_resume

These all get dropped into a directory on the server, and we can point Passenger to look at that directory and serve up those applications.

So my question is: How does nginx come in to play here? Is the nginx configuration for that virtual server completely ignored? We often need to upgrade nginx config for things like rewrites, as well as some passenger configuration (`min_instances`, for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mass Deployment is a feature inside Phusion Passenger Standalone (in Enterprise). Standalone creates Nginx virtual hosts for all those apps. You can specify options through the command line, see --help.